# Workaround for System.Drawing.FontFamily in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, fonts

I have used Segoe UI font from System.Drawing.FontFamily in my wpf application and also i want to use the same font (Segoe UI) in my Silverlight application also. But there is no support for System.Drawing.FontFamily in silverlight.

So anyone please suggest me a workaround to achieve or use Segoe UI font in silverlight application.

Note: i am using interop with winforms, so i cant able to use system.media.fontfamily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
 System.Drawing.Font
```